# URL rewriting : including source files to "index.php" from HTTP requests which don't really exist

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've got a small website at the URL `localhost/site/`. It has got a `.htaccess` file, a `index.php` file and a folder to store images called `img`

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

As the above code every url to `localhost/site` will redirect to `index.php` if the url isn't a directory or a file.

**index.php file**

```
<html>

<body>
    <img src="img/logo.png"/>
</body>

</html>
```

**Problem**

When I go to `localhost/site` or `localhost/site/[any_text]`, it works fine, which is `index.php` will successfully load the file `img/logo.png`.

But if I go to `localhost/site/[any_text]/[any_text]` or further to any sub-directories in `localhost/site` (which really don't exit, only a request) the `index.php` will not load `img/logo.png`

So why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because images that are included without leading slash or another form of locator like a protocol and domain will make the client assume that the path is relative to the currently viewed path. Thus if you are viewing `http://example.com/folder/page.html` the relative image path `img/logo.png` will make the client request `http://example.com/folder/img/logo.png`.

If you instead insert a leading slash you will tell the client that the image is located relative to the root of the site and it will instead result in the client requesting the file `http://example.com/img/logo.png`.

The correct image html code will be:

```
<img src="/site/img/logo.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="/img/logo.png"/>
          ^ note the leading slash
```

Comment: I guess this should be `/site/img/logo.png` due to the directory structure explained in the question.